# Calculate the signature of $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, bilinear-operator

How I can calculate the signature of this inner product?

Let $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n} ( \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined by:

$ f: \space \mathcal{M}_{n \times n} ( \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \space \space f(A,B) := n\operatorname{tr}(AB) - \operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)
  $

I know that this inner product is bilinear and simmetric. So, because it's an inner product we can conclude that the matrix representation of $f$ is positive definite and it has real eigenvalues, but how I calculate the signature of $f$?

Thank you!

Comment: my suggestion would be to notice that the identity matrix $I$ is a null vector.  Then restrict to the space of traceless matrices and calculate the signature; in this space your form is equal to $n\operatorname{tr}(AB) $ and the signature for that is a standard exercise.  More simplistically: solve the simpler problem of calculating the signature of  $g(A,B):=n\operatorname{tr}(AB) $ first.

Comment: Okay, thank you!, I'll try with that suggestion.

Comment: you shouldn't call it an inner product. To get some sense of it, make a 2 by 2 matrix $A$   with entries $w,x,y,z,$   and write out $f(A,A).$  This is a polynomial in variables $w,x,y,z.$   In turn, write out the Hessian matrix of this, which is 4 by 4 matrix of constants. Find the eigenvalues, if you can.

Comment: A part of the solution is [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2149825/305862)

Comment: However, it is not entirely necessary to solve for the eigenvalues, since we mostly  want the signs. See  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Answer (score 1):

Let $\langle A,B \rangle$ denote the inner product
$
\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T).
$
We can express $f$ as
$$
f(A,B) = n \langle A,B^T \rangle - \langle A,I \rangle \cdot \langle B^T,I \rangle
\\ = \left\langle A,n\left[B^T - \frac{\langle B^T,I\rangle}{\langle I,I\rangle} I \right]\right\rangle = \langle A,\Psi(B)\rangle,
$$
where $\Psi(B) = n\left[B^T - \frac{\langle B^T,I\rangle}{\langle I,I\rangle} I\right]$. Notably, we have $\Psi = n\cdot \tau \circ \pi$, where
$$
\tau(B) = B^T, \quad \pi(B) = B - \frac{\langle B,I\rangle}{\langle I,I \rangle}I.
$$
Because $\tau$ is self-adjoint relative to the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $I$ is an eigenvector of $\tau$ associated with the eigenvalue $1$ (equivalently, $\pi$ is the spectral projection associated with the eigenvector $I$), we can conclude that the eigenvalues of $\Psi$ are equal to those of $\tau$ except that one eigenvalue $n$ has been replaced by an eigenvalue $0$.

The eigenvalues of $\tau$ are $-1$ with multiplicity $n(n-1)/2$ and $+1$ with multiplicity $n(n+1)/2$. Thus, the eigenvalues of $\Psi$ are $-n$ with multiplicity $n(n-1)/2$, $+n$ with multiplicity $n(n+1)/2 - 1$, and $0$ with multiplicity $1$.

Thus, the signature of $f$ is
$$
n_+ = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 1, \quad n_- = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}, \quad n_0 = 1.
$$