# An inner product over $M_{n\times n}(F)$ that leaves invariant the entries of any matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, inner-products

Let $V := M_{n\times n}(F)$ be the space of $n\times n$ matrices over a field $F$. As a finite-dimensional vector space, it admitis a finite basis $\{M^{(j)}\}_{j\in [[1,n^2]]}$. Now my question is very general in nature: is there an inner product, symmetric bilinear form (SBF) or Hermitian form (HF) to decompose an arbitrary $M\in V$ over this basis, in such a way that the components of the matrix agree with the components it would have for a given basis of $F^n$?

The question came to mind when I found out that Pauli matrices, together with the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, provide a basis $\{M^{(j)}\}_{j\in[[1,4]]}$ of $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{C})$, and that an SBF allowing a *satisfactory* decomposition of a matrix in this space over that basis is

$$\langle M, N\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(M N)$$

where by satisfactory I mean here that any matrix, expressed in a particular basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$,

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$$

is invariant under the decomposition, i.e.

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} = \sum_j \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(M M^{(j)}) M^{(j)}$$

Now this invariance is dependent on the above specific basis, as it can easily be seen by the fact that over the basis $\{e^{(ij)}: e^{(ij)}_{kl} = \delta_{ki}\delta_{lj}\;\;\forall i,j\in \{1,2\}\}$ the decomposition changes the components. The question, then, can be stated as follows: **is there an inner product, SBF or HF over $M_{n\times n}(F)$ that for a given basis of this space the entries of a matrix (over a particular basis of $F^n$) remain invariant?** In other words, provided a basis $\{M^{(j)}\}_{j\in [[1,n^2]]}$ and a matrix with components $M_{kl}$, how do I build (if possible) one of the aformentionned forms, such that

$$M_{kl} = \sum_j \langle M, M^{(j)}\rangle M^{(j)}_{kl} \;\;\;\forall k,l\in [\![1,n]\!]$$

Comment: I think you should check the Frobenius inner product.

Comment: "One can also check that they are orthogonal in the Hilbert–Schmidt inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{d\times d}$." [Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Generalized_Gell-Mann_matrices_(Hermitian)) This might be a place to start.

Comment: I think I am missing something, but I understand your questions like this: You give me a basis $B$ of $M_{n\times n}$, and you want an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on the space such that for every matrix $m\in M_{n\times n}$, we have $m = \Sigma_{b\in B} \langle b,m\rangle\cdot b$. Then you just want an inner product with respect to which your basis $B$ is orthonormal, no? You can always do that for any vector space $\mathbb{F}^k$, in particular for $\mathbb{F}^{n^2}$: take $A$ the translation matrix from the canonical basis to $B$, and let $\langle u,v \rangle = u^T A^T A v$.

Comment: @OndrejDraganov he product you provide is over $F^n$, not over $M_{n\times n}(F)$. The idea would be to construct an inner product **among matrices** leaving the entries of a matrix (in a given basis of the space it acts on) invariant. I'll check the links in other comments.

Comment: Your question stays the same over any (finite dimensional) real or complex vector space. Simply define $\langle M^{(i)}, M^{(j)} \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ and $\langle \sum_i a_i M^{(i)}, \sum_j b_j M^{(j)} \rangle = \sum_i a_i \overline{b_j}$.

Comment: @reuns How, from that construction, do you actually obtain the coefficients $a_i$? The purpose of my question is, after all, learning how to decompose any given matrix (with specific entries) as a linear cobination of the matrices forming a specific basis.

Comment: As reuns says, the matrices can be unraveled and viewed as just long vectors (length $n^2$). The matrix $A$ I was describing is a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix. I wrote the same as what reuns wrote now (his description being shorter and cleaner)

Comment: I see now. Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant, @OndrejDraganov

Comment: No worries :) If this is truly what you are looking for, and you would like to actually compute the inner product, then one way to go around things is as follows: 1) Unravel your matrices into vectors (say, concatenate rows); 2) Create a matrix $C=(b_1,\dots,b_{n^2})$ having the unraveled vectors of your basis $B$ as columns; 3) Compute the inverse $A=C^{-1}$. This is the transition matrix from $B$ to the canonical basis. 3) To compute the inner product of matrices $u,v\in M_{n\times n}$, you first unravel them to vectors, which I again denote $u,v$, and then compute $u^T A^T A v$.

Comment: your post refers  to $\langle M, N\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(M N)$ as "an inner product" but it is not positive definite which is a contradiction.  Perhaps you are really looking for a symmetric bilininear (or hermitian) form.

Comment: In the spirit of "unraveling" vectors, but without unraveling, consider "elementary matrices" $E_{i,j}$ with a unique 1 entry in (i,j), constituting an orthonormal basis for the "famous" dot product $<A,B>=Tr(A^TB)$. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2150078/305862

Comment: @user8675309 indeed, I am looking for a either a symmetric bilinear form or a Hermitian one (if we talk about $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Indeed quadratic form $Tr(A^TB)$ isn't definite positive. As given in the reference I just indicated, its signature  for $n \times n$ matrices is $\left((+1)^{\frac{n^2+n}{2}},\quad (-1)^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}\right).$